# Python Subprocess reading from stdout blocks (reading output in real time)

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to interact with an application using subprocess.
I've created the process using Popen but I am not able to access the output stream without blocking the whole thread.
Writing to the inputstream however seem to work fine (tested it using communicate, however I may not be able to use this later as I need real time data).

I have already tried putting the buffer to 1 but it doesnt seem to work.

I have noticed that sometimes if the process terminates, the output is flushed.
I do believe that this issue may be caused by the fact that no flushing occurs (and that on closing, all the data gets recived at the same time) but I am not sure.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int testInteger;
    printf("Enter an integer: \n");
    scanf("%d", &testInteger);
    printf("Number = %d",testInteger);
    return 0;
}
```

Python code

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("./a.out", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1, close_fds=True)

print(p.stdout.read(1)) #This should read E but instead blocks the whole thread!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have already tried putting the buffer to 1 but it doesnt seem to work.

The `bufsize` parameter specifies the buffering of the pipe, but the binary you're calling has its own streams buffering which is generally full buffering if the binary is not outputting to a terminal (it's line buffering if stdout is a term).

You can observe this if you change the communication channel to stderr (using fprintf). Or if you `fflush(stdout)` explicitely after the `printf`. Or if you explicitely change the buffering configuration using `setbuf(3)`/`setvbuf(3)` (warning: this is UB unless it's done immediately at program start).

If you do not wish to modify the C program you can also use `stdbuf` (very much GNU-specific) to customise the buffering of the wrapped binary, just replace `"./a.out"` by `['stdbuf', '-o0', 'a.out']` to run `a.out` with an unbuffered stdout.

Incidentally, that sort of mess is why you probably don't want to handroll scripting interactive programs, that's why `pexpect` exists.

Oh, and `stdin` generally has the same buffering as `stdout`, by default (so line-buffered when hooked to a terminal and fully buffered otherwise).

Answer (score -1):

The pipe `read()` waits for the subprocess to terminate before returning the entire output, hence it blocks.

You can try using `readline()` as described in [read subprocess stdout line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line).

*Edit*:

Your c program might need to `fflush(stdout)` after `printf`. If `printf` detects a pipe then it can choose to not flush even with output of `\n`.

See more at [Does printf always flush the buffer on encountering a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229096/does-printf-always-flush-the-buffer-on-encountering-a-newline).

Comment: As far as I know read with an integer arg does not await the entire output but only the number of specified chars. In either way, readline still seem to block the entire thing.